# Unpack a list of dictionary and combine multiple values for distinct keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, python-dataset

I have following dictionary:
`[{'author__name': 'Alexandre Dumas', 'title': 'The Three Musketeer'}, {'author__name': 'Alexandre Dumas', 'title': 'The Count of Monte Cristo'}, {'author__name': 'Leo Tolstoy', 'title': 'Resurrection'}, {'author__name': 'Leo Tolstoy', 'title': 'War and Peace'}, {'author__name': 'Leo Tolstoy', 'title': 'Anna Karenina'}]`

I want the output to be
*Leo Tolstoy: “War and Peace”, “Anna Karenina”, “Resurrection”

Alexandre Dumas: “The Three Musketeers”, “The Count of Monte Cristo”*
What can be the most efficient way to do that. I'm new to python, any sort of help will be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you’ve tried already, so show the *exact* issue and what effort you have put in so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a `defauldict` to group the book titles per author, then print as you need

```
from collections import defaultdict

values = [{'author__name': 'Alexandre Dumas', 'title': 'The Three Musketeer'},
          {'author__name': 'Alexandre Dumas', 'title': 'The Count of Monte Cristo'},
          {'author__name': 'Leo Tolstoy', 'title': 'Resurrection'},
          {'author__name': 'Leo Tolstoy', 'title': 'War and Peace'},
          {'author__name': 'Leo Tolstoy', 'title': 'Anna Karenina'}]

result = defaultdict(list)
for value in values:
    result[value['author__name']].append(value['title'])

for author, titles in result.items():
    print(author, ":", ",".join(f'"{title}"' for title in titles))
```

```
Alexandre Dumas : "The Three Musketeer","The Count of Monte Cristo"
Leo Tolstoy : "Resurrection","War and Peace","Anna Karenina"
```

Comment: Great work ok this.  Encouraging the latest generation of lazy programmers who simply come here for hand-out answers from rep mongers.  Excellent work!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use below code:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = [{'author__name': 'Alexandre Dumas', 'title': 'The Three Musketeer'},
        {'author__name': 'Alexandre Dumas', 'title': 'The Count of Monte Cristo'},
        {'author__name': 'Leo Tolstoy', 'title': 'Resurrection'},
        {'author__name': 'Leo Tolstoy', 'title': 'War and Peace'},
        {'author__name': 'Leo Tolstoy', 'title': 'Anna Karenina'}]

pd.DataFrame(data).groupby("author__name")["title"].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()
```

##### Output

|  | author__name | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Alexandre Dumas | The Three Musketeer,The Count of Monte Cristo |
| 1 | Leo Tolstoy | Resurrection,War and Peace,Anna Karenina |

##### Explantaion

Using `groupby`, you can group over whatever column you like. Then by using `apply` on the title column, you can join the string as exactly as you want.

Comment: Don't say "just use below code", to someone that absolutly don't know what to do? That isn't a simple thing, add explanations

Comment: @azro As you can see I have added an **Explanation** part which I believe is enough. If someone is more interested to know how each of these functions works, he or she can SIMPLY search the documentation.